# Excel TextToColumns FixedWidth

Tags: excel, vba

When using text to columns fixed width, what happens to to the spaces that are used to separate the columns in some files? ( The layout is padded with spaces but also a space separating the columns)

Per Row, the data for each column begins on and ends on or before the following table with another space separating each column. My question is , Should that space be part of the preceding or following column. MS Documentation doesn't even mention about the trimming of whitespace for fixed width at all.

```
CHAR START   CHAR MAX END( spaces will pad out to this char position if data doesn't)
1            12   
14           48 
50           52
54           63
65           68
70           73
75           89
91           102
104          138
140          142
144          EOL
```

This is the code I am using but I am wondering should all char positions after the first column be increased by 1 to be reliable..

```
    Columns("A:A").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(48, 1), Array(52, 1), Array(63, 1), _
    Array(68, 1), Array(73, 1), Array(89, 1), Array(102, 1), Array(138, 1), Array(142, 1)), _         
    TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

SAMPLE DATA WOULD BE

```
    111111111111 AB CDEFGH IJKLMNO PQRSTYV WXYZA       1 11.1 ABC      1    1 ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO 111111111111 AB CDEFGH IJKLMNO PQSTYVW            11 100 ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not add any numbers unless your data is being cut off at the right, or you have leading white spaces in any of your cells.

In your example, you have your second column starting at position 12.  Column 1 has twelve "1's" and no trailing blank space.

Note that the second digit in "Array(0, 1)" denotes the data type.  1 = General, 2 = Text, 3 and above are all date types I believe.  If you choose general for all of them (which you have there) it will automatically eliminate trailing blanks on numbers, converting that value to a number.  If the column value contains any text at all it will be considered text.  If you select "2" for all of these fields it will save your columns as text without any conversion, and the trailing blanks will not be eliminated from numeric values.

Comment: I know about the datatypes ,  my question is there is actually no resulting trailing or leading space using either 12 or 13 , but i'm afraid both cant give the same results all the time... its part of a bigger project and i would like to be sure this part is reliable

Comment: or is the real answer that Excel trims both sides while doing Text to Columns leaving no diffence

Comment: Excel doesn't trim if you use data type 2.  Data type 1 ("General") is dynamic, it behaves different ways depending on the data that lands in the cell.  Try changing your first array to 'Array(0,2)' and your second array to `Array(13,1)', see how that changes things.

Really, if you have the option of delimiting your data file instead using fixed widths, that's more reliable (in my experience).

Comment: believe me , I WISH I had that choice:)

Comment: So I just tried it, it look like Excel does you the favor of trimming leading and trailing blanks.  This is actually a good thing, IMO, nobody benefits from a worksheet full of blanks.  Take into account that I am using Excel 2010, 2003 wasn't nearly as bright.

Answer (score 0):

> When using text to columns fixed width, what happens to to the spaces that are used to separate the columns in some files?

They are removed. The equivalent of TRIM (worksheet function) being applied to each field (the content between the column breaks). `345....DEF` (where the dots here represent spaces) ends up as `345` in one cell and `DEF` in another wherever the divider is placed between `5` and `D`. This is so regardless of the Column data format chosen and regardless of whether the characters are numeric or alphabetic.

As long as your numbers for parsing represent a position next to or within a region of one or more blank spaces between the fields you want separated it makes no difference whether at the beginning of one or more spaces, in amongst one or more spaces either side or at the end of one or more spaces. And no difference whether one space or one hundred.